# why I get netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector although I release the buffer in finally block?

Tags: netty

Here is a gist of my code

```
public static void doSomething(ByteBuf buf) {
        ByteBuf bufCopy;
        try {
            bufCopy = buf.copy();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
            buf.readBytes(bytes);
            try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
              //do something
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("something went wrong", ex);
            }
        }
        finally {
            buf.release();
        }
    }
```

I get the following message in my logs

```
io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector       : LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:331)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:185)
    io.netty.buffer.UnsafeByteBufUtil.copy(UnsafeByteBufUtil.java:436)
    io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.copy(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:309)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.copy(AbstractByteBuf.java:1194)
```

what is wrong here and how to fix this?

By the way, this is **NOT** reproducible always. when I restart the server, error goes away, but once the server is up and running for few minutes, I start seeing this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you missed to release `bufCopy` as well. This is clearly shown in the log.

Comment: why this isn't always reproducible?

Comment: because leak detection is using sampling to reduce the overhead.